# Android code works on phone but not on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

If I run the code on my phone galaxy s2 2.3.6, it works fine.
However, if I try to run on eclipse emulator, it will give me an error.
:(

What the code does is simple viewflipper.

I tried to run on emulator platform 2.3.3 and 4.0.3

Thank you for the help.

bottom is the logcat output.

> 02-21 17:11:39.223: D/dalvikvm(353): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 1645K/2137K, paused 25ms
>   02-21 17:11:39.233: D/skia(353): --- decoder->decode returned false
>   02-21 17:11:39.233: D/AndroidRuntime(353): Shutting down VM
>   02-21 17:11:39.233: W/dalvikvm(353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   02-21 17:11:39.253: E/AndroidRuntime(353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-21 17:11:39.253: E/AndroidRuntime(353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exercise.AndroidViewFlipper/com.exercise.AndroidViewFlipper.AndroidViewFlipperActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class 
>   02-21 17:11:39.253: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>   02-21 17:11:39.253: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   02-21 17:11:39.253: E/AndroidRuntime(353):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   [50+ more]

Comment: I had 3 images; A, B, and C. A and B were less than 10 kb. C was >10MB.

As soon as I reduce the size of C, the emulator started working...

Maybe there is a maximum size that emulator can handle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create the new project, Eclipse asks for target version.
However, it seems like it sets minimum version to that Target version #.

After I change the minimum version, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to this.

Try deleting the emulator instance you are using (I do mean to delete it in the AVD manager) and then  recreate it.  That solved the issue for me.  Also make sure that the emulator is emulating all the features necessary for your app.